# Homebrew OSX Sierra No such file or directory PSQL postgres@9.5

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have the issue from running `psql` after installing with Homebrew

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And have read the other posts and tried their suggestions but nothing has worked:
1.

```
$brew services list

postgresql@9.5 started johndoe /Users/johndoe/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@9.5.plist
```

2.

```
$sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -ls

1202295        8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root             wheel                  26 Sep 26 17:09 /private/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432 -> /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

3.

```
$cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-09-16 16:39:45 PDT
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 25089) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

4.

```
$cd /usr/local/var/postgres
$ls -a

.                    base                 pg_commit_ts         pg_ident.conf        pg_notify            pg_snapshots         pg_subtrans          pg_xlog              postmaster.opts
..                   global               pg_dynshmem          pg_logical           pg_replslot          pg_stat              pg_tblspc            postgresql.auto.conf server.log
PG_VERSION           pg_clog              pg_hba.conf          pg_multixact         pg_serial            pg_stat_tmp          pg_twophase          postgresql.conf
```

So seems like the `pid` is somewhere but where? I tried look in the `private/var/pgsql_socket`but it wasn't there. I've also trie brew stopping and starting postgres.

Comment: and after restart - FATAL in logs is the same but with different date?..